# quartz jboss spring multiple webapps

Tags: spring, jboss, datasource, quartz-scheduler

I have been successfully using quartz in my application.
Basically I have quartz bundled inside the webapp1 which is running inside the Jboss.

But we have got another webapp2 running in the jboss which needs to have quartz job as well

Now what I need to do is to have quartz scheduler running in the jboss as some kind of service and both the webapps should be able
to register their jobs on the single quartz scheduler.

below is my related spring configuration for webapp1 which has beenworking till now.

```
<bean id="qtzScheduler"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="jndiDataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey">
        <value>applicationContext</value>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="schedulerName" value="webapp1" />       
</bean>

<bean id="wrapperScheduler" class="uk.fa.quartz.schedule.ServiceScheduler">
    <property name="scheduler">
        <ref bean="qtzScheduler" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jndiDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:/FmManagerDS</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

when I have to schedule the job,code is like below:

```
   WrapperScheduler scheduler = (WrapperScheduler) ctx.getBean("wrapperScheduler");
   scheduler.scheduleCronJob(job, jobName + "CronTrigger", WrapperScheduler.TRIGGER_GROUP, cronExpression);
```

Now I dont want to define the same scheduler again in webapp2 which will cause 2 quartz scheduler running in the jboss.

Can someone has any idea how to do it ?
I saw one example on the internet like below [Link](http://zunkthoughts.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/quick-howto-quartz-with-jboss.html) which I think is doing what I want.
But I dont understand how I can integrate this with my system using the datasource defined in my spring source.
If anybody can share the configuration or point me to the right resource on internet,I would be highly thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got time to write it all down for all others who might have to use Quartz as a service running in jboss.
But other options as mentioned in his answer by @Tomasz can also be tried.

Please note that you will get a null reference back if you try to retrieve it from outside the JBoss server in which it was bound.  In case you have such a requirement you might want to consider using Quartz's RMI support instead.

1)First of all ensure that you remove any existing versions of the quartz in the jboss/[profile]/lib or the quartz.rar which is comes up with the jboss distribution.

2)Please your quartz.1.8.3.jar & quartz-jboss.1.8.jar into the acccesmanager/[profile]/lib

3)Below is the code for quartz-service.xml which needs to be placed in the jboss deploy folder which will start the Quartz scheduler:

```
    <server> 
     <mbean code="org.quartz.ee.jmx.jboss.QuartzService" 
     name="user:service=QuartzService,name=QuartzService">    
     <attribute name="JndiName">Quartz</attribute> 
     <attribute name="Properties">        
     org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = BGSScheduler 
     org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false 
     org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false 
     org.quartz.scheduler.xaTransacted = false 
     org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool  
     org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5 
     org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 4 
     org.quartz.scheduler.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializer = true
     org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
     org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
     org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass =  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
     org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = QUARTZ
     org.quartz.dataSource.QUARTZ.jndiURL = java:FmManagerDS 
     org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource = QUARTZ_NO_TX
     org.quartz.dataSource.QUARTZ_NO_TX.jndiURL = java:FmManagerDS
     </attribute>     
     <depends>jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=FmManagerDS</depends>
     </mbean> 
     </server>
```

]
Most of things are self explanatory or you can get more details on this at [Quartz Configuration](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/configuration/)
The key thing is to note that quartz requires 2 datasources.One is the container managed datasource-same one as one defined in jboss *-ds.xml(java:FmManagerDS  in my case).
If your 'org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource' is XA, then set 'org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource' to a non-XA datasource (for the same DB).  Otherwise, you can set them to be the same.

Then in spring applicationContext,I had to get the handle of quartz so that I could inject into the wrapperScheduler.Code for that is below

```
    <bean id="quartzScheduler" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName">
                <value>Quartz</value>
            </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="wrapperScheduler" class="k.fa.quartz.schedule.ServiceScheduler">
            <property name="scheduler">
                <ref bean="quartzScheduler" />
            </property>
    </bean>
```

Then we can schedule the jobs using below

```
Timestamp t = new Timestamp (System.currentTimeMillis());
ScheduleJob job = new ScheduleJob(EmailJob.class.getCanonicalName() +t.toString(), EmailJob.class);
```

Below is the code to pass the spring applicationContext to the EmailJob so that we can access beans and other things.
        To achieve that we need to implement the ApplicationContextAware interface so that applicationContext is available and same is then 
        pushed into the schedulerContext.Please ensure that we dont put applicationContext into the JobdataMap incase you are using JDBC store as it gives serialization issues.

```
    serviceScheduler.getScheduler().getContext().put("applicationContext", ctx);
    serviceScheduler.scheduleCronJob(job, "test" + t.toString(), ServiceScheduler.DEFAULT_TRIGGER_GROUP, cronExpression);
```

Others who are not using wrapperscheduler can similarly get the handle of the quartz directly into their code using below

```
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    Scheduler scheduler = (Scheduler) ctx.lookup("Quartz");
    ScheduleJob job = new ScheduleJob(EmailJob.class.getCanonicalName() +t.toString(), Executor.class);
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

In the Email job class you can use below to get the applicationContext

```
       applicationContext = (ApplicationContext) context.getScheduler().getContext().get(APPLICATION_CONTEXT_KEY);
       //get spring bean and do the necessary stuff
```

Another important thing is that as the quartz schedler is running outside the webapplication,quartz wont be able to fire the jobclass if it is inside the war.It needs to be in the shared jar in the jboss/[profile]/lib.

Answer (score 2):

The [link](http://zunkthoughts.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/quick-howto-quartz-with-jboss.html) you refer to explains how to access Quartz scheduler services [built into JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Quartz_scheduler_integration.html). I have never used such approach but basically you let JBoss handle your scheduler, data source and everything around it. This makes it very easy to take advantage of job scheduling without all the configuration hustle - but is not very flexible and your application is no longer self-contained.

In your case I see two options worth investigating:

## Clustered Quartz scheduler

Configure both of your web applications to [run in a cluster](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering). Both applications will share the same database and will run jobs defined in each other. This might not be an option for you due to several reasons:

- both applications must be able to run jobs defined by each other - e.g. job classes must be available on CLASSPATH
- you still need to define Quartz configuration in both applications (you can easily share configuration though, e.g. by extracting the XML configuration into a separate file)
- both applications will maintain separate thread pool

Clustering is more suited for homogeneous applications running on several machines, not heterogeneous ones on single node.

## Remote scheduler

Quartz has a [built-in support for remote schedulers](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigRMI) via [rmi](/questions/tagged/rmi). Basically one application hosts full-blown Quartz server whilst the other connects to that server. This seems like a better approach for you (let's call it "*master-slave*") as only one application manages the scheduler while the other uses existing one.

See: [`RemoteScheduler`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/impl/RemoteScheduler.html).

Comment: Thanks for giving me a headthrough.Does that mean I will have to create one more webapp3 which will act as quartz server and webapp1 & webapp2 will use it or I can have quartz server running inside one of webapp1 and have webapp2 use the same.But in both the cases I think jobclasses wont be available to the calling webapp.Can you please throw some light on this ?

Comment: @Rips: you're right, you can either create `webapp3` or use one of existing apps to host Quartz. About CLASSPATH problems - you will never get away without them - JVM/classloader running your jobs must have access to job classes - in all scenarios.

Comment: we are not using unified classloaders in jboss so  the classes in one webapp wont have visiblity across to the stuff inside the other webapp2.
Does that mean that all the jobclasses and the classes that it uses for business logic need to be put inside the webapp that hosts the quartz. ?Isnt there any other option left for me then ?